# jquery post error 500

Tags: c#, javascript

I have used the JavaScript code to call a method in the c# class (method provided in code). When is does a post back I get an error 500, I would like to know how I can fix this so that I call the method.

JavaScript to call c# class method

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
    url: "TestChapter.aspx/timeFinished",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //
    }
});
```

Method in C# class testchapter.aspx:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void timeFinished() {
    // my code is here 
}
```

Comment: Debug your method, it's throwing an error

Comment: What happens when you call `TestChapter.aspx/timeFinished` in the browser?

Comment: Statuscode 500 means internal server error. So the code in your timeFinished method is throwing an unhandled Exception. To help you, we'll need your code for that method and some more information on the error

Comment: Since you're requesting JSON format, your method should be decorated with `[ScriptMethod]` (unless your web service class is already decorated with `[ScriptService]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method in C# class *testchapter.aspx*, it might work:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void timeFinished() {
    // my code is here 
}
```

Have a look at [this post](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you certainly missed the `/` char in your ajax method url, it should be:

```
url: "/TestChapter.aspx/timeFinished",
```

The other thing is that you should log the error to the console, it's easier that way:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "/TestChapter.aspx/timeFinished",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (result) {
         // do something
     },           
     error: function (data) {  // handle your error loging in here
         var errorDetails = data.responseText.replace("{", "").split(',');
         var errorMessage = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < errorDetails.length; i++) {
            if (errorDetails[i].split(':')[0] == "\"Message\"") {
                errorMessage = errorDetails[i].split(':')[1];
            }
         }
            alert("Error:" + errorMessage);
});
```

It will write all errors in the debugger console, it's a lot easier to find errors.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa Yes, it does. No `/` in the url is an error, so adding it is needed. Logging the internal server error is also a solution, because ot shows what is wrong on server side.